# How to create a custom CSS progress bar

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, progress-bar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s6Dv.png)

I need help in creating the attached control in HTML5.

1. It needs to resize properly as the page it resides on changes.
2. Need ability to change colors of the circles as the progress changes.
3. Need ability to change colors of the bridges as the progress changes.

I tried the following, but it does not seem to work well. It was hard to set the  element to match the positions of the numbered circles. Also the positioning of the circles is difficult to maintain.

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px;">
     <div class="col-md-12">
        <svg height="24" width="24" style="float: left!important;">
            <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="blue" />
            <text x="9" y="9" fill="white">1</text>
        </svg>
        <svg height="24" width="24" style="float: left!important; margin-left: 25%">
            <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10" stroke="white" stroke-width="3" fill="white" />
            <text x="9" y="9" fill="black">2</text>
        </svg>
        <svg height="24" width="24" style="float: left!important; margin-left: 25%">
            <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10" stroke="white" stroke-width="3" fill="white" />
            <text x="9" y="9" fill="black">3</text>
        </svg>
        <svg height="24" width="24" style="float: left!important; margin-left: 25%">
            <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10" stroke="white" stroke-width="3" fill="white" />
            <text x="9" y="9" fill="black">4</text>
        </svg>
        <svg height="24" width="24" style="float: right!important;">
            <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10" stroke="white" stroke-width="3" fill="white" />
            <text x="9" y="9" fill="black">5</text>
        </svg>
        <progress value="20" max="100" style="width: 100%; height: 24px; display:block;" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With below example, you get a nice-looking progress stepper component, which is easily customizable at the same time. The lines that connect the different steps are represented as ::before and ::after pseudo-elements.
Keep in mind that if you decide to scale the element containing the step, you should also change the top value of the pseudo-elements. Also, you can refer [this example](https://codepen.io/lookininward/pen/LYpxPPo) if you want to change progress color upon completion.

```css
.stepper-wrapper {
  margin-top: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.stepper-item {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;

  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}

.stepper-item::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  top: 20px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.stepper-item::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.stepper-item .step-counter {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.stepper-item.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.stepper-item.completed .step-counter {
  background-color: #4bb543;
}

.stepper-item.completed::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 2px solid #4bb543;
  width: 100%;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.stepper-item:first-child::before {
  content: none;
}
.stepper-item:last-child::after {
  content: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="stepper-wrapper">
  <div class="stepper-item completed">
    <div class="step-counter">1</div>
    <div class="step-name">Welcome</div>
  </div>
  <div class="stepper-item completed">
    <div class="step-counter">2</div>
    <div class="step-name">Property Details</div>
  </div>
  <div class="stepper-item active">
    <div class="step-counter">3</div>
    <div class="step-name">Coverage Info</div>
  </div>
  <div class="stepper-item">
    <div class="step-counter">4</div>
    <div class="step-name">Discounts</div>
  </div>
  <div class="stepper-item">
    <div class="step-counter">5</div>
    <div class="step-name">Get Quote</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch!! Does just what I want.